# Закругленный фон в счётчике Navigtion Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Нужно сделать закругленные края в счётчике Navigation Drawer, на картинке, без использования библиотеки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка взята отсюда: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer
Перерыл всю библиотеку, но не понял каким образом это реализуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым. Необходимо создать xml файл с именем: kruglie_ugli.xml, в него положить данный участок кода. И использовать в коде: tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kruglie_ugli);

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<solid android:color="#000000"/>
<padding
    android:top="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:right="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Shape отвечает за форму элемента, solid - за заливку, stroke - за границу, corners описывает углы.

Но вот незадача, не реагирует на изменение отступов. И никак не могу установить выравнивание их по середине.